# Having bigger images for a xlarge screen in android

Tags: android

I am building an android application on version 2.2, I need to support for extra large screen. Layout rendering is no problem, but there are some devices which are extra large but are mdpi.
It is taking all the drawables from drawable-mdpi, I want my layout to take bigger images for xlarge screen, I have even defined drawable-xlarge for loading bigger images but still the images are getting loaded from drawable-mdpi folders.

My other drawable folders are

drawable-ldpi which has images of dimension of 32 by 32.
drawable-mdpi which has images of dimension of 48 by 48.
drawable-hdpi which has images of dimension of 72 by 72.
drawable-xhdpi which has images of dimension of 96 by 96.

then for extra large screens I have drawable-xlarge which has images of 108 by 108.

How to make android load bigger images for xlarge screens. App is not getting loaded with images from drawable-xlarge, are there any changes I should carry out to get bigger images loaded into xlarge screens rather than from drawable-mdpi folder.

Any help or pointers would be helpful.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to provide several other more specific qualified resource folders, such as `drawable-xlarge-mdpi`. Going by the information in [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources), it *should* work the way you have it (i.e. screen size qualifiers should take precedence to density qualifiers) but it seems that for you it isn't working as expected. Are you certain it's an `xlarge` display? If so, I would try placing your images into `res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi`.

Comment: yes I was trying on ASUS Transformer, it comes in extra large mdpi category. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look it will be better if you make separate layout for x-large screens refer supporting multiple screens from android developers site 
as the android system will fetch images from mdpi,hdpi,ldpi or xhdpi according to the screen density not according to the size

Comment: I have used `dp` units and `relative layout`, `match parent`, `fill parent` and `wrap content`, so I dont need to have seperate layout for extra large screen. thanks.

Comment: if you use an extra layout which loads images with different name then you can easily support that x large screen with your desired images

Comment: how do you load different screen layouts, will the layouts have same name or not, if different then I have to check for the size of the screen and then load the appropriate screen, that's what you want to have different layouts. but even after screen size can be same but density will differ from different machines. thanks.

Comment: no need to check for the size just put the layout in layout-xlarge for 3.0 and higer use sw-600 and tags like that pls refer supporting multiple screens thanks buddy